# Как задать порядок выполнения событий (анимаций)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, очередь

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Делаю скрипт к **html**-шаблону. Есть фрагмент в коде `<div id="target" ...>`. Необходимо сделать плавный скроллинг к нему по клику на ссылку `<a href="#target">`.

Проблема в том, что на этом клике висит ещё одно событие, которое скрывает некоторые элементы со страницы. Из-за этого положение координат целевого элемента смещается. Если бы обе анимации выполнялись неодновременно, а по очереди, то всё работало бы корректно.

Каким образом можно добавить в очередь выполнения функцию(событие), чтобы получить координаты для скроллинга после того как ранее установленные скрипты закончат скрытие элементов?

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html lang="ru-RU">
   <head><title></title><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
   <body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   /* Этот фрагмент нельзя менять */
   $(function(){
     $('a[href^="#"]').click( function() {
      $('#hideme').hide(1000);
     });
   });
   /* Далее всё что угодно */

   $(function(){
     $('a[href^="#"]').click( function() {
       var sc = $(this).attr("href");
       var dn = $(sc).offset().top;
       // sc - в переменную заносим информацию о том, к какому блоку надо перейти
       // dn - определяем положение блока на странице

       alert('Положение блока на странице по вертикали '+dn+' (Ошибочное)');

       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: dn}, 1000);
       // 1000 скорость перехода в миллисекундах 

       $('a').remove();
     });
   });


   </script>


   <a href="#target">Перейти к фрагменту</a>
   <div id="hideme" style="display:block;width: 100%; height: 500px; background: green;"></div>
   <div id="other" style="display:block;width: 100%; height: 1200px; background: yellow;"></div>
   <div id="target" style="display:block;width: 100%; height: 300px; background: red;"></div>
   <div id="other"  style="display:block;width: 100%; height: 700px; background: blue;"></div>
   <div id="other"  style="display:block;width: 100%; height: 700px; background: magenta;"></div>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод `hide` у `jquery` вторым параметром принимает функцию, которая выполнится по окончанию анимации. ( [документация](http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete) )

```js
$('#test').on('click', function () {
    $('#to-hide').hide(1500, function() {
         $('#to-show').show();
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: #333;
}

#to-show {
  display: none;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'></div>

<div id='to-hide'></div>
<div id='to-show'></div>
```

Comment: спасибо за вариант.. но у меня нет доступа к данному фрагменту кода, чтобы внести изменения, т.к это код одной из билиотек фреймворка.. я могу только дописать свой фрагмент